# Quick Integration Approximation Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So I was given the following question:

"The continuous function $f$ is defined on the interval $-5 \leq x \leq8$. The graph of $f$, which consists of four line segments, is shown in the figure above. Let $g$ be the function given by $g(x)=2x+\int_2^1f(t)dt$. Find $g(0)$ and $g(-5)$."

[image]

I'm a bit confused on how I'd go about tackling something like this. Would I literally just take the given values of $f(x)$ on the graph and use then in finding the values that were asked for? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. I think that if they give you a picture, then it might be because they want you to extrapolate data from it *(also notice that it gives you the scale of the plane)*. But you can just use the marked points as a reference to reconstruct $f(x)$ using the equation of a line given two points.

> Would I literally just take the given values of $f(x)$ on the graph and use then in finding the values that were asked for?

In that sense, you're right. You would have to integrate $f(x)$ within the given bounds by first reconstructing it. This is how it should look like:

> \begin{equation} f(x)=\begin{cases}2x+6, &\text{ if }&-5\leq x< -2;\\-\frac{1}{2}x+1, &\text{ if }&-2\leq x <0;\\x+1, &\text{ if }&0\leq x < 2; \\ -x+5, &\text{ if }&2\leq x\leq 8.\end{cases} \end{equation}

However, you could just reconstruct the function within the integration bounds.

Note that the previous part implies that:

> \begin{equation}\int_{2}^{1}f(x) \ dx=-\int_1^2f(x) \ dx=-\int_1^2 (x+1)\ dx = (?).\end{equation}

Finally, you have to evaluate $g(x)$ at the given values of $x$.